# How to use date format as constant in C#?

Tags: c#, date, datetime, tostring

I'm using "yyyy-MM-dd" several time in the code for date formatting

For example :

```
var targetdate = Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Is it possible to declare the format as constant, so that use of the code again and again can be avoided

Comment: Why not change the culture so it will automatically applied all over

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this as

```
const string dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";

//Use 
var targetdate = Date.ToString(dateFormat);
```

OR

```
//for public scope
public static readonly string DateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";

//Use
var targetdate = Date.ToString(DateFormat);
//from outside the class, you have to use in this way
var targetdate = Date.ToString(ClassName.DateFormat);
```

Comment: Yes. The `const` can exist locally withing the body of a method (accessor, etc.), or it can be a direct member of a `class` (or `struct`). If it is in a class, it can be declared (for example) `internal`, `protected` or `public` to be accessible from other classes. If accessed from another non-deriving class, use `NameOfClass.DateFormat` to Refer the `const`.

Answer (score 10):

Use an extension method without declare any format again and again like this:

```
public static class DateExtension
{
    public static string ToStandardString(this DateTime value)
    {
        return value.ToString(
            "yyyy-MM-dd", 
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

So you use it in this way

```
var targetdate = Date.ToStandardString();
```

Comment: You should mention that the method has to be static in a static class.

Comment: I'd suggest using the invariant culture here, too - I *very* much doubt that the OP wants this affected by culture.

Answer (score 3):

Another option that you can do is use the `DateTimeFormatInfo` overload on `.ToString(...)` rather than the `string` overload.

```
public static readonly System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo MyDateTimeFormatInfo
    = new System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo()
{
    ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd",
    LongTimePattern = "",
};
```

Now you can do `var targetdate = DateTime.Now.ToString(MyDateTimeFormatInfo);` which is much the same as using string, but you have a lot more control over many other formatting properties.